# lejos filewriting to the NXT

Tags: java, file-io, lejos-nxj

I am new to java and lejos so please don't blame me if i'm asking rather dumb questions.

I was trying to let the lego ultrasonic sensor scan a 360 degree area around my nxt by rotating it on a motor. Every 5 degrees it saves the distance to a .txt file.

My problem is that later when I read the file from my PC after uploading it with nxjbrowse.bat, it only contains the ASCII characters linked to the numbers that supposed to be saved there (0 - 255).

My code for the NXT:

```
package Dataloggers;
```

import java.io.*;
import lejos.nxt.*;

public class USdistance {

int totalRotation = 360;
int scanDensity = 5;
UltrasonicSensor ultrasonicSensor = new UltrasonicSensor(SensorPort.S3);
File distanceFile = new File("Distances.txt");
FileOutputStream fileStream = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    USdistance usD = new USdistance();
}

public USdistance() {
    Motor.A.setAcceleration(2000);
    Motor.A.setSpeed(50);   

    try {
        fileStream = new FileOutputStream(distanceFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LCD.drawString("Can't make a file", 0, 0);
        Button.ESCAPE.waitForPress();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(fileStream);

    Motor.A.rotate(90);
    Motor.A.resetTachoCount();
    Motor.A.backward();

    do {
        if (-(Motor.A.getTachoCount()) % scanDensity == 0 ) {
            int distance = ultrasonicSensor.getDistance();
            try {
                dataStream.writeInt(distance);
                fileStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LCD.drawString("Can't write to the file", 0, 1);
                Button.ESCAPE.waitForPress();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    } while (-(Motor.A.getTachoCount()) < totalRotation);

    Motor.A.stop();

    try {
        fileStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LCD.drawString("Can't save the file", 0, 1);
        Button.ESCAPE.waitForPress();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Motor.A.rotate(270);
}
}

Thanks in advance Rob

Comment: Can you give a snippet of the .txt file that your code produces?

Comment: It produces this: ㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㐀5㐴㐀3㌴㐀4㐴㌀6㌳㌀3㈳㌀2㈳㌀2㈳㌀2㘳㌀6㘳㌀6ㄳ㌀1ㄳ㌀1ㄳ㌀2㈳㌀4㐳㌀4㔶㘀7㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㈶㘀2㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㈲㈀3㔲5㔲5㔲5㌲㈀6㠲㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀2㈲㈀3㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㔲5㐵㔀3㈵㔀2㈵㔀2㈵㔀2㈵㔀2㌵㔀3㌵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵

Comment: Is there any way to specify an encoding when you create the `File` or `FileOutputStream`?

Comment: by the way. If I don't plug in my sensor, ultrasonicSensor.getDistance() will get the value 255. Then the text file only contains a lot of 'ÿ' and the decimal code of this character is 255.

Comment: Definitely sounds like an encoding issue

Comment: Is it possible ultrasonicSensor.getDistance() returns a byte value instead of an int value, because if I replace dataStream.writeInt(distance) with dataStream.writeInt(255) it does work.

Comment: Doesn't look like it: http://lejos.sourceforge.net/p_technologies/nxt/nxj/api/lejos/nxt/UltrasonicSensor.html#getDistance\(\)

Comment: Then I still don't know what the problem is..

Comment: I don't think the NXT is encoding the results incorrectly; I think Java is encoding the text file with the wrong encoding.

Comment: I solved my problem by using a 'BufferedOutputStream buffStream' than I only needed to use: 'buffStream.write(distance.getBytes());' and it works perfectly. But I still don't know why  'dataStream.writeInt(distance)' didn't work.

Comment: Not sure. Glad you solved it though. You should create an answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using: 
`int distance = ultrasonicSensor.getDistance();` 
`BufferedOutputStream buffStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(distances.txt)));` 
`buffStream.write(distance.getBytes());`
By using this my text file looks like this: 41 41 0 0 0 0 0 0 40 40 40 40 40 39 39 39 39 39 39 40 40 40 40 instead of  㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㐀5㐴㐀3㌴㐀4㐴㌀6㌳㌀3㈵㔀2㈵㔀2㈵㔀2㈵㔀2㌵㔀3㌵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀㔵㈀
Anyway thanks for your replies @SimpleCoder